# Driving in Israel with a US learners permit

Tags: driving-licenses, israel

Can a US citizen drive in Israel with a New York State learners permit?

Answer (score 5):

No, Israel does not recognise foreign learners permits, only full (valid) licenses and even then they require you to meet the age restrictions Israeli licenses are issued under.

http://rishuy.mot.gov.il/en/driving-licences/46-israel-fdl